# Issue checking count at index 0 in swift while Objective-C as bridge

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Sorry if this is really simple question but I am having difficulty in finding out count of NSArray following is technique I follow that goes in crashing the code.

**Swift:**

```
var employeeInfoArray: NSArray = []

var savedValue: String?
savedValue = defaults.stringForKey("FromToDuration")
employeeInfoArray = [EmployeeDatabase .sharedSingletonDatabase().evaluationList(savedValue)]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (employeeInfoArray[0].count)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var simpleId: String?
    simpleId = "EmpTableViewCell"

    let cell:EmpTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleId!) as! EmpTableViewCell
    cell.empNameLabel.text = employeeInfoArray[0][indexPath.row].name
    cell.empIDLabel.text = String(employeeInfoArray[0][indexPath.row].uniqueId)

    return cell
}
```

My employeeInfoArray has data in following hierarchy coming from a bridge from Objective C model:

```
NSArray
->NSArray
-->Employee1 (MyCustom Class Object)
-->Employee2 (MyCustom Class Object)
-->Employee3 (MyCustom Class Object)
```

[image: On Request for detail Hierarchy]

**Issue:**

When I return 3 in numberOfRowsInSection I am able to display all 3 employees details on tableView.

When I return (employeeInfoArray.count) I get only 1 Employee details Viewed

When I return return (employeeInfoArray[0].count). It Crashes.

Now how can I get count of 0 index ?

*Please don't mark it as duplicate I tried searching this question from last 4 hours.*

Comment: One thing that I tried was after retrieving data when I write following statement

`let nameOfEmployee1 = textArray[0][0].name
            let idOfEmployee1 = textArray[0][0].uniqueId
            
            print(nameOfEmployee1)
            print(idOfEmployee1)` 


It gives error that Ambiguous use of name but uniqueId is working perfectly fine. now what is this going on ?

Comment: What is the crash?  This is very unsafe code and will crash when `employeeInfoArray` is empty as it will be when this view controller first loads. You should check for an empty array and return 0. Your data structure seems quite awkward too. Why do you have the nested array rather than just an array of Employee objects?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am new in IOS Swift just started this week. Can you please guide me how can I have just array of EmployeeObjects. What I am doing is just 
`employeeInfoArray = [EmployeeDatabase .sharedSingletonDatabase().evaluationList(savedValue)]` It is creating array of array of employee by itself.

Comment: Get rid of the `[]` around the statement; it is putting the value inside an array.  Just say `employeeInfoArray = EmployeeDatabase .sharedSingletonDatabase().evaluationList(savedValue)`

Comment: **My mistake, I figured out the crash**. I was going out of bounds that was leading to crash. @Paulw11 Thanks for your comment and it would be great if you could help me with some guidelines in improving my code structure.

Comment: What you are saying is correct but I am declaring this as global var and then saving value in viewDidLoad so this is the reason I am doing `var employeeInfoArray: NSArray = []` without [] it gives error that my class has no initializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily putting your employees inside another array by using the `[]` around the outside of your array access.

You should also make your code more robust in the event that the defaults value is missing. Also, in Swift there is no need to declare the type of a variable if Swift can infer it from the value that is assigned.

Finally, minimise the use of `NSArray`; get the data into a Swift array as soon as you can, since then the contents are typed.

```
var employeeInfoArray = [Employee]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let savedValue = defaults.stringForKey("FromToDuration") {
         employeeInfoArray = EmployeeDatabase.sharedSingletonDatabase().evaluationList(savedValue) as! [Employee]
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return employeeInfoArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var simpleId = "EmpTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleId, foIndexPath: indexPath) as! EmpTableViewCell
    let employee = employeeInfoArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.empNameLabel.text = employee.name
    cell.empIDLabel.text = "\(employee.uniqueId)"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks but after your above code of viewDidLoad there is error that `Cannot assign value of type '[AnyObject]!' to type '[Employee]'`